# load mod_wsgi failed on apache 2.2

Tags: windows, apache, wsgi

All,

I want add mod_wsgi modules to my local apache 2.2 server. But when I add "LoadModule module_wsgi modules/mod_wsgi.so" into https.conf file. the apache service will be unable to started. follow error is added to error.log file.

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `module_wsgi' in file C:/Apache2.2/modules/mod_wsgi.so: No error

For additional information, folloing is my computer's settings.

1. My computer is run Windows 7 system.
2. I had install xampp 1.8.1 (It has built in apache 2.4 service). And I install apache 2.2 with a standalone setup package. and binding it to port 8888. If I don't add wsgi module. it work normal. So, my computer has two apache service instances.
3. I had install python 2.6.6 in my system and add c:\Python26 in my system path.